# How to pass the varible value from one layer to other layer in flash actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript

[image: ,]

Hello below is the image of my project , you can see dice layer with 25th frame and at 25th frame its having a variable value and I need to pass it to JS layers 1st frame which is another layer down the roll layer please do the needful.

Comment: Layers don't matter at all with variables,  frames do however.  If you create a variable in the first frame, you can read/write to in all subsequent frames (regardless of the layer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

**dice / frame 25 :**

```
// here the String type is just for example of course, set the type of your var
// the shared_var var is global, so you can use it in any frame of any layer
var shared_var:String = 'data'
```

**JS / frame 1 :**

```
// we have to verify if shared_var is defined and not null 
// because in the first iteration of your animation, shared_var does not exist yet because it's defined in the frame 25 
if(shared_var){

    // here trace is just for example, you do what you want with your var
    trace(shared_var)  // gives : data

}
```

Comment: here I am trying to move pawn according to dice roll frames 25,the randomly generated number is in one layer called dice layer and the  pawn movement is in another layer i.e,. named layer JS frame 1, but after every dice roll the pawn is going back to zero means that its resetting...

Comment: @Kogile You want reset it in JS/frame 1?